# How does one link an image URL to another URL to display some information about the first URL in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, url, hyperlink, gesturedetector

I am trying to create a hyperlink to link each and every image's URL in my code so that a user can be directed to another page with information about the image that was clicked on. How do I go about doing that?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  // This holds a list of fiction users
  // You can use data fetched from a database or a server as well
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allHerbs = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "plant1",
      "urlImage":
          'https://www.southernexposure.com/media/products/originals/sweet-genovese-basil-809aaf7e3d9a3f3fa7ce2f0eb4480e95.jpg'
    },
    {"id": 2, "name": "plant2", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 3, "name": "plant3", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 4, "name": "plant4", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 5, "name": "plant5", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 6, "name": "plant6", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 7, "name": "plant7", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 8, "name": "plant8", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 9, "name": "plant9", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 10, "name": "plant10", "urlImage": ''},
  ];

  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _foundHerbs = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    // at the beginning, all users are shown
    _foundHerbs = _allHerbs;
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = _allHerbs;
    } else {
      results = _allHerbs
          .where((user) =>
              user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _foundHerbs = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Herb Search'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _foundHerbs.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _foundHerbs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                        key: ValueKey(_foundHerbs[index]["id"]),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        elevation: 4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Text(
                            _foundHerbs[index]["id"].toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_foundHerbs[index]['name']),
                          subtitle: Image.Network('${_foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"]} '),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text(
                      'No results found',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `TextButton` and on the `onPressed` method use the launch method from [the URL launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Comment: @h8moss That should be posted as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer. There is no mechanism for converting comments to answers, so I cannot do it for you. You will need to copy your comment into the answer box and then delete your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, for each image clicked, you want to be directed to another page containing information about the image.

One way to go about it is :

1. For the data being fetched, you could modify to :  `{"id": 2, "name": "plant2", "urlImage": '', **"urlInfo" :""**}`
2. Since you want to launch a url, you could use the `**url_launcher package**` or a suitable package, based on how you want to access the information. Use a WebView package if you want to access the information in-app.
3. You're using ListTile so you could do :
   When using url_launcher package

   ```
    ListTile(
    onTap: () async{
             await launch('${_foundHerbs[index]["urlInfo"]} ');
    },
   ),
   ```

Or for something like flutter_webview_plugin, you could do :

```
ListTile(
onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => WebviewScaffold(
      url: '${_foundHerbs[index]["urlInfo"]} ',
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Image Information"),
        withJavascript: true,
      ),
    ),
   ),
  );
},
),
```